# TSQL Reverse LIKE Statement

Tags: t-sql

To give you context here is my db schema.

Fruit Table

```
Id     Name
1      Gala Apples
2      Navel Oranges
3      Peach
4      Mandarin Oranges
5      Kiwi
6      Fuji Apples
```

Intersect Table:

```
FruitId     CrossRefFruitId
   1              6
   2              4
```

So my intersect table has the fruit values.

```
1 (Gala Apples) are related to 6 (Fuji Apples)
2 (Navel Oranges) are related to 4 (Mandarin Oranges)
```

In the UI say the user is viewing details about Gala Apples. I want to be able to have a "See Also: Fuji Apples".

Now I'm told that I do NOT want to have reverse entries so 1,6 is good but it is a waste to have 6,1 which makes sense.

So I'm trying to write a TSQL check that will identify if 1,6 or 6,1 exists.

Ultimately this would go into an INSERT trigger that would check the incoming row to see if the combination exists then allow insert or skip.

Googling I find REVERSE which is for reversing a string and end up with a lot of hits for EXCEPT and INTERSECT.

So even just knowing the proper terminology to google so I can self educate would be appreciated.

Comment: How does `CrossRefFruitId` relate to `FruitId` in your schema - could you show it?

Comment: Updated to show reference...hopefully I understood your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table #test
(
id1 int,
id2 int
)

insert into #test
select 1,6
union all
select 2,5
union all
select 6,1
union all
select 5,3
union all
select 5,2


select * from #test  t1
where exists(
select  1 from #test t2 where t1.id1=t2.id2 and t1.id2=t2.id1)
```

**Updating as per question:**

Your trigger should contain below line of code which checks existence of rows which are reversed..

```
if   exists(
select 1 from
#test t1
join
inserted i
on i.id1=t1.id2 and i.id2=t1.id1
)
begin 
rollback tran
--some message---
end
```

Comment: 1, 6 would trigger 4, 3?

Comment: Cool use of a join...thanks for taking the time to help.